Dynamic Pricing for Events
We manage a number of events where we ask for donations and have previously offered standard amounts (e.g. £10, £20, £50) as well as an 'Other' option - a field where donors can select their own amount to donate. Can anyone suggest a way we can do this in Civi/Spark? Ideally, we'd also like to provide the option for donors to set the amount to be taken as a 'one off' or 'monthly'/regular frequency. Thanks.

Hi Welcome. You can do this in a Price Set. I can't imagine CiviSpark does not offer this. You set a field to be just a $1 text entry so folk can put whatever amount they want. see https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&action=preview&id=1 and https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/price/field?reset=1&action=browse&sid=3

I will change the above to an answer if you confirm i haven't misunderstood the question.
